What is the fewest number of shots for a winning team in a Stanley Cup Playoffs game?
The Edmonton Oilers beat the Dallas Stars 2-1 in game 6 of the 2024 Western Conference to advance to the Stanley Cup Finals.
The Oilers won the game only registering 10 shots on net! In the post game analysis it was mentioned not only it was the lowest number of shots on net for the winning team on a series clinching game, but also any playoff game.
What are the top 5 lowest number of shots on net for the winning team on any NHL playoff games?

Here are two examples of teams who won in the playoffs while registering 10 shots on goal

https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/199004090WSH.html
https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/197404130LAK.html

Statmuse backs this up - https://www.statmuse.com/nhl/ask/least-shots-to-win-a-playoff-game
There are two teams that won with 11 SOGs. Thus, the top 5 you're looking for is:

6/2/2024 EDM vs DAL (10)
4/9/1990 NJD @ WSH (10)
4/13/1974 CHI @ LAK (10)
4/22/2016 PHI @ WSH (11)
5/13/1998 WSH @ OTT (11)


It's interesting how often the winning team does this while playing on the road.

Wow have to go back back 30+ years for the last one!
